# Custom menu problems

Tags: wordpress

I'm starting on Wordpress world, I have been reading some tutorials from wp.tutsplus.
I have been checking that tutorial many times but I can't find my mistake.

The problem:
Wordpress is not printing my menus, I can create them on wp panel but it is not printing anything my menu is located at header.php and it is the main one.

Here's the functions.php:

```
function register_my_menus(){
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'main-menu' => __('Menú Principal' , 'HICA')
        ));

}

add_action('init', 'register_my_menus');

?>
```

Here's the header.php

```
<nav>
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'main-menu'
        )); ?>

    </nav>
```

Comment: I found the mistake... I didn't assigned a page name to the menu. Sorry folks, my bad u.u

Answer (score 0):

try this

functions.php

```
function register_my_menus(){
    register_nav_menu('main-menu','Menú Principal');
}
add_action('init', 'register_my_menus');
```

header.php

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main-menu')); ?>
```